# YouTube API - How do I include the link I have generated?

Tags: video, iframe, google-api, youtube-api

I have set up a Google Cloud project and enabled the YouTube API, I have then followed the documentationn to generate a googleapi link like so:

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId={????}rmcE40wikDHMzBqN6QsD4BGs8wx5&key=AIzaSyCSqQqPYMVr3OgYWJ2QvpO1J1idCpb{????}&maxResults=50](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=%7B????%7DrmcE40wikDHMzBqN6QsD4BGs8wx5&key=AIzaSyCSqQqPYMVr3OgYWJ2QvpO1J1idCpb%7B????%7D&maxResults=50)

I have a simple question that hopefully has a simple answer, how do I include this into my website so it will show what I have requested through the API link?

I have tried to put it in the SRC of an iFrame and cannot find any alternative solutions online.

The response from the iFrame is:

```
www.googleapis.com refused to connect.
```

The console also returnns:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.googleapis.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

Appreciate this is has a very high chance of me looking silly but hopefully will save someone else in the future too!

———

*EDIT*:

I guess I am asking, I know how to generate a link according to the docs on the YouTube API, how do I then use it to do what the link instructs?

Comment: `I have tried to put it in the SRC of an iFrame`= not sure if I understand = with this, you want to get the results in a iframe - like, the response of the API? - I think you have to set your API to allow your API key certain domains; I can't really test right now, but, give it a try to your project API key settings. Also, consider [edit] your question and add the desired result - no need to add the API_KEY, just leave it as `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=[YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID]&key=[MY_API_KEY]%7D&maxResults=50`

Comment: Thanks, question somewhat updated c: